# in java guava Sets.difference，How does it work

Tags: java, guava

I have read the source code but I saw that it just creates an anonymous instance and overrides some method.
In executed difference method, these overriden methods are not executed.
So how does it implement the difference set?

Comment: Are you talking about https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java#L880? It returns a `SetView` implementation whose methods _are_ executed... when you call them, not before. Note how the methods only return elements from `set1` if they are not contained in `set2`. That's where the "difference" is implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sets.difference`, as per the docs, tell:

> ```
> public static <E> Sets.SetView<E> difference(Set<E> set1, Set<?> set2)
> ```
>
> Returns an unmodifiable view of the difference of two sets. *The returned set
> contains all elements that are contained by set1 and not contained by
> set2*. set2 may also contain elements not present in set1; these are
> simply ignored. The iteration order of the returned set matches that
> of set1.

As the doc already tells, `Sets.difference` make use of Set's `contains()` method in order to achieve the operation of difference.

You won't directly be able to check the operation in guava's src, as `contains()` is just a function declaration in the interface, so has no implementation and must be implemented by the structures that [implement the `Set` interface](https://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Set-source.html).

For example, a `HashSet` (which uses a `HashMap` under the hood) will use `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods, while other implementation may utilize `compareTo()`, or `compare()`, if a `Comparator` is used.